# Apache CAMEL process on file presence

Tags: file, apache-camel, esb, talend

I have a use case that I can't find a way to implement it, here it is: with an FTP connexion, I need to get only files named with specific prefix from a list. (example of file names format FileA_20170210073006539.csv, FileB__20170210073006475.csv, FileC_20170210073006485.csv).

I can only process those files when they are all together with the same date.

What I do first, is copying the files with a filter on theses 3 prefixes, and then I think to use an aggregator, but I can't find a method to do that. For example if I have in my FTP folder

1. FileA_20170209073006539.csv
2. FileB__20170209073006475.csv
3. FileC_20170209073006485.csv
4. FileA_20170210073006539.csv
5. FileB__20170210073006475.csv
6. FileC_20170210073006485.csv

I must begin by processing the FileX_20170209 files (the oldest ones).

Aand if I have only:

1. FileB__20170210073006475.csv
2. FileC_20170210073006485.csv

I must wait for FileA_20170210 presence. Can I use an aggregator for it? if yes how?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Where do you have the list from? You can sort the files, and then use a filter filter, where you can return true|false if you have all of the files. In the file filter you can store state, so you can remember the previous file, so you can check that they are A .. B .. C in that order. This then becomes a little bit tricky as the first time you need to say false and then on 2nd poll you would know if A B and C existed and can return true to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do :

tWaitForFile --> tFTPFileList --> your process

In these two component you can use the "*" to make a mask in order to filter your files like

- `"*20100708"` to take only the file witch finish by `"20100708"`
- `"FILE_A*"` to take only the file witch begin by `"FILE_A"`